# How to make a functioning to do list in java

Tags: java, arrays, list

I am trying to make a functioning to do list with a limit of 10 elements, however I am having an issue with two major things in the to do list.

The first is that after I first compile and run the program and select to add elements to the list, that functions properly, but if I add two elements and the 'stop' sentinel, when I select the next option to print the to do list, I am presented with a list, showing my two elements and then the stop sentinel along with 7 null values in the list. So the first issue I am having is to get rid of the null values, I attempted using a counter as you can see in my code however that was not proving to be effective.

The next issue that I am having is that I am trying to make it so that you can add to the list, so once you select to add more things to the list, the new options the user writes, rewrites over them in the array and prints out the new values and not along with the old ones. I am assuming that can be done through some sort of recursion method but I am having a hard time figuring it out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ToDo {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    final int MAX = 10;

    String[] list = new String[MAX];
    int choice = 0;

    while (choice != 3) {

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Type 1 to add a new thing to your to do list.");
        System.out.println("Type 2 to print the to do list.");
        System.out.println("Type 3 to exit the program.");
        System.out.print("Select an option: ");
        choice = input.nextInt();
        int count = 0;

        if (choice == 1) {
            System.out.println("Keep hitting enter after to do's, if you want to stop, type 'stop'.");
            for (int i=0;i<MAX;i++) {
                list[i] = input.nextLine();
                if (list[i].equals("stop")) break;
                count++;
            }
        }

        if (choice == 2) {
            for (int index = 0;index < list.length; index++) {
                System.out.println(list[index]);                    
            }               
        }

    }

}
}
```

Comment: One easy option would be to remove the `String[]` and use `ArrayList<String>` instead... That has all the API's you need...

Comment: I have not learned about ArrayList<String>, would my for loop add values to that list or would I have to rework my loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I have mentioned in the comment, you can use an `ArrayList` instead of `String[]` to make your processing much easier.

But if you want to use the array itself, there are 3 minor issues with your code.

In your choice 1 for loop, start the loop from `count`,

```
    for (int i=count;i<MAX;i++) {
        list[i] = input.nextLine();
        if (list[i].equals("stop")) break;
        count++;
    }
```

In your choice 2 for loop, end the loop before reaching `count`,

```
    for (int index = 0;index < count; index++) {
        System.out.println(list[index]);                    
    }
```

And move your count initialization outside the while loop.

```
int count = 0;
```

But beware, if you decide to implement removing tasks, this could get complicated and using `ArrayList` would become much simpler.

Comment: When I run this and attempt to print the list, it returns me with a blank result, any idea what could be doing that?

Comment: You need to move the count initialisation outside the while loop... Fixed in in the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a fixed size array of Strings, use an ArrayList of Strings. Then you can add elements to it as you go.

Make sure to

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

Declaration syntax is

```
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Add elements to your list with the  add() method:

```
myList.add(input.nextLine())
```

You don't need that inner for loop, instead break out of the while loop of input options when you've iterated through it 10 times.

To solve your problem of "stop" being in your list, check that the input is "stop", and  stop,  *before* you attempt to add to the list.

Comment: Just starting out so of course I am going at things the more difficult way, teaching myself about strings, but I appreciate the advice! Thanks for the response!

Comment: No problem...may I suggest..try both ways as you learn. ArrayLists will come in handy sooner or later.

Comment: I'll be sure to look into the documentation for it!

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use `ArrayList` but if you still want to stick to `String[]` then the following program will work for you:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        final int MAX = 10;
        String[] list = new String[MAX];
        int choice = 0;

        while (choice != 3) {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Type 1 to add a new thing to your to do list.");
            System.out.println("Type 2 to print the to do list.");
            System.out.println("Type 3 to exit the program.");
            System.out.print("Select an option: ");
            choice = input.nextInt();
            String userEnteredItem;
            if (choice == 1) {
                System.out.println("Keep hitting enter after to do's, if you want to stop, type 'stop'.");
                for (int i=0;i<MAX;i++) {
                    userEnteredItem = input.nextLine();
                    if(!userEnteredItem.isEmpty()) {
                        list[i] = userEnteredItem;
                        if (userEnteredItem.equals("stop"))  {
                            break;
                        }
                        count++;
                    } else {
                        i--; // Do not increase index for empty item.
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (choice == 2) {
                for (int index = 0;index < count; index++) {
                    System.out.println(list[index]);
                }
            }
            else {
                input.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

It keeps track of user items in static int `count` and it also closes the scanner when you do not need it.